# How can I pair SSH keys for connecting to remote server?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

For the sake of having security up to scratch on my LAMP server I generated ssh keys and tried to pair them with my server. Sadly it failed on server's side.

Here's the steps I followed:

typed command `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Entered out prompts for passphrase (these are optional) and I left them blank.

It successfully generated public and private keys.

Typed `ssh-copy-id root@my_server_id`

Was prompted for root password. Entered, however I got error line saying "Permission denied. Try again".

I'm 100% sure about the password but still get this error and when I try to login into my server I get prompted for password and access is granted but not for keys ???

What can I do ? I can login into my server but can't pair ssh keys with my server.

Comment: post the whole output you are getting from `ssh-copy-id`. In recent versions it is quite clever and connects two times if I recall correctly.

Comment: Is the root account enabled? is password-based SSH login permitted for root?

Comment: This is the output from `ssh-copy-id root@server_ip` :

`/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
root@192.xxx.x.x's password: `

and when I enter root password it says permission denied and try again. I'm certain I'm missing something here because at this point I should be prompted on server-side to confirm pairing. The pairing was successful when I was doing this x months ago.

Comment: To answer your question, Steeldriver, I suppose root account is always enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, please try to log in as root over ssh with -vv 
eg:

`ssh root@my_server_id -vv`

I think it will tell you what exactly is wrong with your permissions.
Probably your persmissions for .ssh directory are too wide and ssh does not like this at all :)

I think your /root/.ssh directory must have permissions set to 700

`chmod 700 /root/.ssh`

and file .ssh/authorized_keys should be set to 600

`chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Strange, when I typed `sudo chmod 700 /root/.ssh` it said "no such file or directory"  ???

Comment: Here's the full output from `ssh root@my_server_id -vv`: https://codeshare.io/50Aqgv